# Remove Microsoft.Powershell.Utility module from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to remove module Microsoft.Powershell.Utility from powershell through Remove-Module. The command succeeds but after that I am still able to use commands from that module, like Format-Hex. What am I missing? I attach a screenshot that shows the behavior

[image]

My environment is a Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Don't do that. "The Utility module contains cmdlets that manage the basic features of PowerShell." **basic features**

Comment: Why do you want this removed?

Comment: You might want to run `Get-Command -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` before doing anything drastic - as @Ben mentions there are a lot of very important/commonly-used commands in that module (e.g. `Get-Date`, `Export-Csv`, `Write-Host`), not just the one you mention.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to remove a specific cmdlet but I cannot find any other way than removing the entire module.

Answer (score 6):

As [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/587803/ben) notes, **unloading module `Microsoft.Powershell.Utility` is ill-advised, because it contains many important cmdlets** (see list below).

**The reason that the module's commands automatically reappear is PowerShell's [module auto-loading feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules#module-auto-loading)**, which loads (imports) modules located in the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath` *automatically, on demand*.

You can prevent auto-loading by setting the [`$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#psmoduleautoloadingpreference) preference variable to `None`, for instance.

Note that **in the case of [name conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules#modules-and-name-conflicts)** - if multiple modules contain commands of the same name:

- Whatever module was imported *last* "wins" - unless you used `Import-Module -NoClobber`, in which case importing fails.
- You can use also *selectively* import from a module, using the member-type-specific `-Cmdlet`, `-Function`, `-Alias` and `-Variable` parameters.
- You can use `Import-Module -Prefix` to attach a prefix to the imported members in order to make their names unique, which in the case of cmdlets and functions goes before the *noun* part; e.g., `Import-Module -Prefix Bar ...` would rename a cmdlet named `Get-Foo` to `Get-BarFoo`).
- Finally, if there are duplicate names, you can disambiguate by prepending the module name to the member name in the form `<ModuleName>\<command>`; e.g., `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Format-Hex`.

---

The list of cmdlets that come with module `Microsoft.Powershell.Utility`, as of Windows PowerShell 5.1:

```
PS> (Get-Command -Module Microsoft.Powershell.Utility).Name
ConvertFrom-SddlString
Format-Hex
Get-FileHash
Import-PowerShellDataFile
New-Guid
New-TemporaryFile
Add-Member
Add-Type
Clear-Variable
Compare-Object
ConvertFrom-Csv
ConvertFrom-Json
ConvertFrom-String
ConvertFrom-StringData
Convert-String
ConvertTo-Csv
ConvertTo-Html
ConvertTo-Json
ConvertTo-Xml
Debug-Runspace
Disable-PSBreakpoint
Disable-RunspaceDebug
Enable-PSBreakpoint
Enable-RunspaceDebug
Export-Alias
Export-Clixml
Export-Csv
Export-FormatData
Export-PSSession
Format-Custom
Format-List
Format-Table
Format-Wide
Get-Alias
Get-Culture
Get-Date
Get-Event
Get-EventSubscriber
Get-FormatData
Get-Host
Get-Member
Get-PSBreakpoint
Get-PSCallStack
Get-Random
Get-Runspace
Get-RunspaceDebug
Get-TraceSource
Get-TypeData
Get-UICulture
Get-Unique
Get-Variable
Group-Object
Import-Alias
Import-Clixml
Import-Csv
Import-LocalizedData
Import-PSSession
Invoke-Expression
Invoke-RestMethod
Invoke-WebRequest
Measure-Command
Measure-Object
New-Alias
New-Event
New-Object
New-TimeSpan
New-Variable
Out-File
Out-GridView
Out-Printer
Out-String
Read-Host
Register-EngineEvent
Register-ObjectEvent
Remove-Event
Remove-PSBreakpoint
Remove-TypeData
Remove-Variable
Select-Object
Select-String
Select-Xml
Send-MailMessage
Set-Alias
Set-Date
Set-PSBreakpoint
Set-TraceSource
Set-Variable
Show-Command
Sort-Object
Start-Sleep
Tee-Object
Trace-Command
Unblock-File
Unregister-Event
Update-FormatData
Update-List
Update-TypeData
Wait-Debugger
Wait-Event
Write-Debug
Write-Error
Write-Host
Write-Information
Write-Output
Write-Progress
Write-Verbose
Write-Warning
```